# How to open the excel file creating from pandas faster?

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas

The excel file creating from python is extremely slow to open even the size of file is about 50 mb.

I have tried on both pandas and openpyxl.

```py
def to_file(list_report,list_sheet,strip_columns,Name):
    i = 0
    wb = ExcelWriter(path_output + '\\' + Name + dateformat + '.xlsx')
    while i <= len(list_report)-1:
        try:
            df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv(path_input + '\\' + list_report[i] + reportdate + '.csv'))
            for column in strip_column:
                try:
                    df[column] = df[column].str.strip('=("")')
                except:
                    pass
            df = adjust_report(df,list_report[i])
            df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors ='ignore', downcast = 'integer')
            df.to_excel(wb, sheet_name = list_sheet[i], index = False)
        except:
            print('Missing report: ' + list_report[i])
        i += 1
    wb.save()
```

Is there anyway to speed it up?

Answer (score 0):

## idiom

Let us rename `list_report` to `reports`.
Then your `while` loop is usually expressed as simply: `for i in range(len(reports)):`

You access the `i`-th element several times. The loop could bind that for you, with: `for i, report in enumerate(reports):`.

But it turns out you never even need `i`. So most folks would write this as: `for report in reports:`

## code organization

This bit of code is very nice:

```
        for column in strip_column:
            try:
                df[column] = df[column].str.strip('=("")')
            except:
                pass
```

I recommend you bury it in a helper function, using `def strip_punctuation`.
(The list should be plural, I think? `strip_columns`?)
Then you would have a simple sequence of `df` assignments.

## timing

Profile elapsed [`time()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.time). Surround each `df` assignment with code like this:

```
    t0 = time()
    df = ...
    print(time() - t0)
```

That will show you which part of your processing pipeline takes the longest and therefore should receive the most effort for speeding it up.

I suspect `adjust_report()` uses the bulk of the time,
but without seeing it that's hard to say.

Comment: Thank you for replying. However, the problem is not how much time it takes to run the code. This code works fine. The problem is excel file creating from this code. When I want to open it, It takes about 40 - 60 seconds to open even the file size is not large. I am sure that this is not usual because I have already compared the time to open between excel file, same data, that is created by using python and not using python.

Comment: I think I hear you suggesting a workaround of (slowly) manually opening it in Excel and re-saving. Thereafter opening apparently goes faster. No, I don't know how the details of the on-disk binary encoding would differ. Your approach of converting cells to floats or integers seemed like a good one. Possibly there is more to be done on that front, like massaging date / timestamps? Comparing time to open "same" sheet, text vs integer, would be of interest.